# How to filter a pandas dataframe without headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I'm trying to filter a larger csv that does not contain any headers. I would like to return a second dataframe that only returns the rows where there is positive values in the last column.

Here is what I'm trying;

```
input_data = pd.read_csv(infile, delimiter=',').values
print(input_data.shape)  # (832650, 200)
pos_data = input_data.iloc[:, 199] > 0
```

The last line gives the error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'

I'm on 0.24.1 of pandas and 1.16.1 of numpy.

Thank you

EDIT:
Removing values, gets rid of the error, but I still can't filter the dataframe.

```
input_data = pd.read_csv(infile, delimiter=',')
print(input_data.shape)  # (832650, 200)
pos_data = input_data.iloc[:, -1] > 0
print(pos_data.shape)  # (832650,)
```

Comment: remove the `.values` while reading the file and try the same , `.values` converts a pandas object to numpy. you can also access the last column by `df.iloc[:,-1]` (fyi)

Comment: thanks but this is doing the sames as; pos_data = input_data[:, -1], it's not filtering just returning the last column.

Comment: how about `input_data.loc[input_data.iloc[:, -1] > 0]` ?

Comment: `pos_data = input_data[input_data[:, 199] > 0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
input_data = pd.read_csv(infile)
df = input_data[input_data.iloc[:, -1] > 0]
```